# Phonegap app crashes sometimes on resuming from camera

Tags: android, cordova, android-camera

I am using phonegap camera to capture images like this

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
        quality : 50,
        sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        destinationType : destinationType.FILE_URI,
        encodingType : Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
    });
```

Please note its only some time that app crashes

I have already tried changes in manifest such as

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
```

here is my logcat

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the quality parameter from 50 to 30 stopped the camera API from crashing the app

edit 1 on samsung galaxy s3

On the Samsung Galaxy 3 the developer option Do not keep activities is on by default.

This will garbage collect your main activity when you launch any other, in this case the Camera.

Switching off the option solves the problem.